# Destructor as private throws compile time error

Tags: c++

If i create an object on stack, its constructor would get called. Its destructor would be called during the end of execution of main or when it goes out of scope etc. But *calling of destructor when an object goes out of scope* happens during Runtime. Then why is it a compile time error if i make the destructor private?
My expectation according to my understanding is that there should be no compile time error and during the execution the object should get created on stack without any error, however as the object goes out of scope there should be some run time error(or crash or whatever). Why is it not the behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visibility is a compile-time feature: you check for a set of constraints at compile-time to ensure run-time safety (to a certain degree). When a program is compiled into a release binary all information regarding private/public stuff is lost. Those constructs help you writing good, safe, maintainable code but are not intended as runtime error checkers.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has to generate code to invoke the destructor where the object goes out of scope.

Visibility is enforced at compile time, so if the destructor isn't visible where the compiler needs to generate code to invoke it, the compiler will normally issue an error message and reject the code.

In theory, the standard only requires a compiler to issue a "diagnostic" (with little definition of what that constitutes) so a compiler could, theoretically, be set up to print out a warning of some sort, and allow compilation to complete (and generate code to invoke the destructor where the object goes out of scope, even though the destructor isn't visible, or possibly to throw an exception, or just about anything else it wants to). In reality, I can't quite imagine a compiler doing anything like that (making a dtor private is usually done specifically to *prevent* an object from being instantiated), and I don't know of any real compiler that's ever worked that way.